# Javascript Sign-on, Basic knowledge

Tags: php, javascript, authentication

I'm building a small website in my spare time, at the moment solely based on HTML, Javascript, PHP (though my PHP skills are rudimentary) and a simple MySQL db. Now I would like to extend this project by allowing users to login to their own account, in order to have highscore lists (I have some small laborative Javascript games on my site) and some really basic community features.

My knowledge of dealing with the sign-on process, handling/encrypting login credentials and related stuff are close to none. So I would just need some piece of guidance, based on mentioned techniques. Where/how should I start, in order the learn these things?

- Are there any JS frameworks out there, for handling login functionality?
- Does anyone know of any good tutorials or other readings on this topic? I've tried to scan the Interwebs, but with no prevail.
- What should/must I consider?
- And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logins are best handled with PHP rather than JS because with PHP you can use your database to save usernames and password etc. With JS your users need to be hardcoded in the script which is very very insecure and can be seen by anyone when checking the source code.

Try this tutorial to get a better understanding of making a simple PHP login system:http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL.

When you're done with the tutorial you'll be definitely capable of making a login system.

I wish you the best of luck and hope it'll help you out!

Comment: That's actually a great guide. Spot on what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm happy that you find my answer usefull. Could you mark this post as answer so other people with this question can also use it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure thing. This question has been put on hold though, since it apparently didn't qualify as on-topic. My bad obviously. I don't know what happens with stalled questions if I don't change it to fit into the requirements (which I cannot do, since the question itself is no more specific than already stated, and doesn't contain any actual code that I need help with). But hopefully it will remain in its present state, for others to find.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you just need to jump in the deep end of the pool, so I am going to recommend you try to implement login via OPENID so that people use their existing Yahoo or Google accounts to log in.  Actually, it works with a few dozen providers....

This means you do not have to store people's passwords or mail them reset links, so there are long term benefits to doing things this way.

People lie about their real name on Yahoo or Gmail all the time, but at least you'll get an email address and some sort of name out of them that they are also possibly using elsewhere.

Here is a PHP library for OPENID: https://github.com/openid/php-openid

Comment: That's actually a great idea, although I will do this as a second step. My first goal is to gain a deeper understanding of the principles behind sign-on and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Authentication section from [PHP Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Authentication) to implement basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Start with HTML authentication using JS and PHP. This is a good place to start:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php. After this (slightly inflexible but useful) method is mastered, you can design your own way using JS and Ajax. Just do not assume that there is any guarantee of security inherent in any of these techniques (there is none). For that you need SSL on top of whatever authentication scheme you are using.

Here is a link that handles HTML auth in full detail:
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html
but basically Google around for HTML authentication with PHP and JavaScript.