# How to create a password protected website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in the middle of creating my website and I need to create password protected JavaScript code to access it.

Do I need to change my CSS as well, or it will be only in my HTML code?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not in some server-side language? JS protected site is a low protection site.

Comment: Search for `.htaccess password protection`. I don't know what you want with javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328637/javascript-sign-on-basic-knowledge/18328818#18328818

Comment: You can use any third party BaaS provider for authenticate your javascript code like http://api.shephertz.com/app42-docs/user-management-service/#authenticate

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Front-end **JS is a *bad* protection**

```js
// IMPORTANT: This is a JS-for-fun - and a BAD example how to secure your content:
var password = "demo"; // because ANYONE CAN SEE THIS IN VIEW SOURCE!


// Repeatedly prompt for user password until success:
(function promptPass() {

  var psw = prompt("Enter your Password");

  while (psw !== password) {
    alert("Incorrect Password");
    return promptPass();
  }

}());


alert('WELCOME');
// or show you page content
```

**To properly protect your page**:
a secured connection with your server, and a server-side language is the way to go.

Comment: Client-side javascript isn't "bad protection", it isn't protection at all.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris - have you considered adding your own answer to this instead of just editing everyone else's?

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible to have any kind of meaningful password protection using pure JS since the client can just change the code of your page to skip the password protection entirely. You'll need to either use HTTP basic access authentication or use some kind of server-side scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use javascript or css to create Password Protected website.

You have to use server-side scripting like **php, asp.net, jsp** or user **htaccess password protection**

Answer (score 0):

You can just put all this in an echo statement in php to just hide the code

**The html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <p>Click the radio button to toggle between password visibility:</p>
    
    Password: 
    <input type='text' value='' id='myInput'><br><br>
    <input type='checkbox' onclick='myFunction()'>Show results
    
    <p id='demo' style='display:none; color: black;'>demo</p>
```

And now the javascript it is quite simple

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById('myInput');
      var y = document.getElementById('demo');
      if (x.value === '45') {
        y.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        y.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    </script>
```

and close the html

```
    </body>
    </html>
```

done that's it just try it and enter the password 45